# Side wall damage

Tags: tires, sidewall-damage

[image]

Is this okay to drive on? Recently noticed this after getting some curb rash on the rim the car is basically new. Dealer told me it’s cosmetic damage but I’m not to sure

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: This has been "answered" many times before.  While it does look minor, it would be irresponsible for anyone to offer an opinion.  Is there any cord damage underneath the rubber flap?

Comment: After lifting up the flap there isn’t an cords that I can see it will be going to the service center this weekend so I assume I will be told by them if the tire needs to be replaced

Answer (score 3):

Your dealer told you correctly ... at least from what I can see. This appears to only be cosmetic in the sidewall rubber. The normal litmus for sidewall damage is as long as you aren't seeing sidewall cords, there's no bulging, or you're not losing air, the tire should be fine. Keep an eye on it, as if you see any of these things in the future, you'll want to get it replaced. Sidewalls cannot be repaired.

Comment: Thank you for the advice! I’m actually taking it to the service center hopefully they’ll give me an answer to this. I don’t see any sidewall cords or bulging. The tire has not had any air loss as well