# Sidewalks damage continued

Tags: tires, sidewall-damage

[image]

I had asked about [this “cosmetic” damage done to my sidewalk due to curb rash earlier throughout the week](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/60504/4152). Would putting some adhesive such as rubber cement be okay for this. As shown I don’t see any cords. It is at the dealership currently getting something else fixed I assume they’d look at the tires

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could use some rubber cement. It's not going to cause you any issues. It will help with the cosmetics of the tire, but won't do anything to the functionality. There are other products you could use on it as well, but you shouldn't have any issues doing as you're suggesting.

Comment: @Jav_3 - If this answers your question, please select it as such :o)

Comment: In the good old days of urban parallel parking, It was common to see all the lettering worn off the sides of the tires . But I don't remember seeing divots like the one in the photo. Is something else going on ?

Comment: To be honest I just got this car and noticed it had some curb rash the other day. Saw this in the tire but it could’ve been my sibling who did this the tire is new I don’t see any cords and no air was coming out as it happen last Saturday and I’ve been driving like this all week and nothing even went on the park way a few times